# How can I validate input does not contain specific words?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my signup form I have a nickname field that users can enter text in to identify themselves on my site. In the past some users have entered nicknames which others might find offensive. Laravel provides validation functionality for forms, but how can I ensure that a form field doesn't contain words users might find offensive?

Comment: Did you tried the [not_in](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-not-in) rule?

Comment: Doesn't do what I need - in/not_in check if the whole field value is in/not a list: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Validation.Validator.html#641-652 . The answer below checks if the list items are contained anywhere in the field.

Comment: Ah! Got it! You are right, thanks to clarify.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whilst Laravel has a wide range of validations rules included, checking for the presence of a word from a given list isn't one of them:

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#available-validation-rules

However, Laravel also allows us to create our own custom validation rules:

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

We can create validation rules using `Validator::extend()`:

```php
Validator::extend('not_contains', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Banned words
    $words = array('a***', 'f***', 's***');
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

The code above defines a validation rule called `not_contains` - it looks for presence of each word in `$words` in the fields value and returns false if any are found. Otherwise it returns true to indicate the validation passed.

We can then use our rule as normal:

```php
$rules = array(
    'nickname' => 'required|not_contains',
);

$messages = array(
    'not_contains' => 'The :attribute must not contain banned words',
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Comment: The [not_in](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-not-in) rule doesn't do the same?

Comment: Doesn't do what I need - in/not_in check if the whole field value is in/not a list: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Validation.Validator.html#641-652 . The answer below checks if the list items are contained anywhere in the field.

Answer (score 3):

Since Laravel 5.6 you can use the `not_regex` rule to check for the existence of a string.

For example, validate a form input that expects a name for a dog:

```
public function update(Request $request) {

  $custom_validation_messages = [
    'not_regex' => "C'mon! Be original. Give your dog a more interesting name!"
  ];

  $this->validate($request, [
      'pet_name' => ['not_regex:/^(fido|max|bingo)$/i'],
    ], $custom_validation_messages);

  ...
}
```

In this case if the submitted `'pet_name'` value is:

- fido
- FIDO
- MaX
- MAx
- BinGO
- bingo
- etc.

Then validation will fail.

For the inverse of this (i.e. you only want Fido, Max or Bingo) then you could use the `regex` rule like so:

```
[ 'regex:/^(fido|max|bingo)$/i' ]
```

See [Laravel Validation (not regex)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-not-regex).